# Can a Blazor API project share the same localhost endpoint with the client?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor

As far as I can tell, the model for creating a Blazor client application is to have one project for the client and another for the server. The Microsoft template shows an async call to get data, but it's just a download of a static JSON file. Any real application would need to call an API.

So I have a separate API project for this. But that project has a different localhost endpoint for debugging, and this is causing a CORS nightmare for me. My call from client to server isn't really cross-site, except for this debugging problem, so I don't want to do a ton of work figuring out CORS.

How can I get the Blazor client and web api server to run off the same localhost (or alias) domain, so that the client can make same site requests?

Comment: You will have to be clear about Blazor-ServerSide or Blazor-WebAssembly.

Comment: DIfferent endpoints indicates ServerSide, but then: Why?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's what the template created. I'm happy for them to share the same project, but this doesn't seem possible either, because one is Standard and the other is Core.

Comment: Sounds like you created 2 independent projects. Look at Peter's answer instead. The "Wasm Hosted" template should have everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

When you create a new Blazor Web Assembly app there is a tick box for hosting it in ASP.NET.

If you tick that checkbox then you'll get a server that both serves the client page (via _Host.cshtml) and also responds to web api calls.